# Using insert rows in a UITableView

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, insert, editing

I'd like my UITableView to behave like the the table in the Contacts editor, i.e. the user should hit Edit and an "add new category" row should appear at the bottom of each section.

I'm using the below code to do this, but the problem is that there is no smooth transition as there is in Contacts.  Instead, the new row suddenly appears.  How can I get the animation?

Also, how do I respond to clicks on the "add new category" row?  The row is not clickable in my current implementation.

Do I need to reload the data when the user starts editing?  I am doing this because otherwise the insertion rows are never drawn.

Thanks.

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // ...
    if( self.tableView.editing ) 
        return 1 + rowCount;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // .....
    NSArray* items = ...;
    if( indexPath.row >= [items count] ) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"add new category";
    }
    // ...

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray* items = ...;

    if( indexPath.row == [items count] )
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert;

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful (along with the answer, below). Just one minor inconsistency - the comparison to row count in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` uses `>=` while the one in `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` uses `==`. Not a big deal, but should be consistent between them. `>=` would cover any accidental double-adding of the Insert row, while `==` would help by throwing an exception for any code errors that could lead to that situation.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I was missing one thing.  In setEditing:, instead of calling reloadData I should have done:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated]; // not needed if super is a UITableViewController

    NSMutableArray* paths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // fill paths of insertion rows here

    if( editing )
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    else
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];

    [paths release];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Bill, this was very useful to me. I spent several hours mucking about in similar code but couldn't get it quite right. This helped immeasurably.

Comment: what about commitEditingStyle: forRowAtIndexPath ?  The Apple documentation says setEditing is called when the table view first goes into editing mode... How would you know what rows to insert/delete at that point?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: I figured that when swiping a single row the method -setEditing:animated: is called. In this case you would not want to insert a row with a "+" button. (Maybe this is what shim meant?)

Answer (score 5):

Responding to clicks on the row might be done in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method, for `indexPath.row == [items count]`. For the animation, I suggest taking a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:), at the `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` method. There's a post on how to use it [here](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=8708412).

Answer (score 0):

An unwanted side effect of the highlighted solution is that the "add" row is inserted also when the user just swipes one single row (provided that swiping is enabled). The following code solves this dilemma:

```
// Assuming swipeMode is a BOOL property in the class extension.

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Invoked only when swiping, not when pressing the Edit button.
    self.swipeMode = YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.swipeMode = NO;
}
```

Your code would require a small change:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated]; // not needed if super is a UITableViewController

    if (!self.swipeMode) {

        NSMutableArray* paths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        // fill paths of insertion rows here

        if( editing )
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
        else
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
        [paths release];
    }
}
```