# iPhone UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have an iPhone application that has a `UITabBarController` that houses multiple `UITableViews`.  I need to be able to add items to each `UITableView` (inside each tab), but my Google-fu is failing me so epically that I cannot find examples of how to put in the "+" button in the upper right corner, in the navigation item. This "+" button would open a subview to enter the new item's information, which I should be able to handle once I get the button to appear. I'd like to do this programatically, not through IB. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: I believe your answers are here: [Using insert rows in a UITableView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470898/using-insert-rows-in-a-uitableview). I found this by searching "uitableview add row" in google.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the button in the right of the Navigation bar like this:

```
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
```

The button will need to be a UIBarButtonItem. You can create the UIBarButtonItem and add a target for when the button is pressed, like this:

```
button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(method:)];
```

The target and action (selector to call when it is pressed) can be changed to whatever you need.

Together, in one line, it looks like this:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(method:)];
```

This should be all that is necessary to create an add button, and add it to the navigationItem.

The previous answer, that talked about using a UIButton is below:

> This is how you'd create a regular
>   button, if necessary:
>
> ```
> UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
> [button addTarget:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed)
> ```
>
> forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
>
> That will call addButtonPressed in the
>   class where you created the button,
>   when it is pressed. You can change the
>   target and selector to whatever you
>   need.
>
> Together:
>
> ```
> UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
> [button addTarget:self action:@selector(addButtonPressed)
> ```
>
> forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
>       self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
>   = button;

Hope this helps!

Comment: Turns out it needed to be a UIBarButtonItem, not a plain UIButton.  It did get set to self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.

Comment: Ah, interesting! Thank you for pointing that out. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

set UIBarButtonItem to self.navigationIten.rightBarButtonItem and handle its action.
To add rows use insertRowAtIndexPath method of tableView.