# Insert a row at position UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a table view in which I want to insert a new row at some position. I have done like this but its giving unexpected output. Am I doing anything wrong here.

```
 NSIndexPath *indexpath =  [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:position inSection:0];

NSArray *temp_array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:indexpath, nil];

[self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:temp_array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```

Do I need to do anything more than this. This I'm doing in a separate function (insert_at_position:)
Any help is appreciated...

Comment: What unexpected result you are getting?

Comment: Pandey-Many rows are gone white, here and there some rows are present.

Comment: You can get help from the below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470898/using-insert-rows-in-a-uitableview

Comment: You can get help from the below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470898/using-insert-rows-in-a-uitableview

Comment: What's my doubts is do I need to do anything in delegates or any other methods after doing this insertion?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
[self.table beginUpdates];
[self.table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:temp_array withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
[self.table endUpdates];
```