# New row on clicking edit button in UITableViewin swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am trying to get a new row in bottom like "insert new cell" with plus button on left in UITableView when user clicks on edit button and goes away when user clicks on done button. Right now I getting plus button on the last row of table view but I am not able to add dynamically a new row. Can anyone help what should I do or is their any better way to do this?

I went to this answer on stack overflow  [Using insert rows in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470898/using-insert-rows-in-a-uitableview)
but I am not getting

```
NSMutableArray* paths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

what this statement is for.

This is my code

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.tableView.editing == true {
            return nameArray.count + 1
        }
        else
        {
            return nameArray.count
        }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        if indexPath.row >= nameArray.count
        {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "insert new row"
        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel?.text = nameArray[indexPath.row]
        }

        cell.showsReorderControl = true
        return cell
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
            nameArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
        else if editingStyle == .Insert{
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("insertNameSegue", sender:nil)
        }
}


override func setEditing(editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setEditing(true, animated: true)
        self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
        tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: You need to implement  `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` - in this method check if you are editing and if it was the last "add" row that was selected - if so, perform your segue to the insert view

Answer (score 0):

This is Objective C:

```
NSMutableArray* paths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

For Swift, you should use Array

```
var paths = Array<NSIndexPath>()
paths.append(NSIndexPath(10, 0))
...
```